# Featured Questions

Tags: support, bounty

There is no section saying 'Featured Questions' in the 'Unanswered Questions Tab'.
How do I find those questions that have active bounties on them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Featured" tab only appears if there are featured questions to show. Currently, I don't think we have any active bounties, which is why the tab isn't there.

Also, as far as I know, the tab appears on the main home page and under "Questions". It doesn't appear in the "Unanswered questions" section.

Comment: Now a featured question has come.